# Haskell -Changing a Char to another specified Char in a specified position in a String

Tags: haskell

I have been learning some Haskell and I came up with a solution to one of my exercise which I was trying to figure out .

- Changes a Char to another specified Char in a specified position in a String

```hs
changeStr :: Int -> Char -> String -> String
changeStr x char zs = (take (x-1) zs) ++ [(changeChar (head (take x zs)) char)] ++ (drop x zs)
```

- Changes a Char to another Char

```hs
changeChar :: Char -> Char -> Char
changeChar x y = y
```

I just wanted to ask is there any other way in which I could do this in a more simpler way using different methods ?

Answer (score 2):

The thing that screams for generalization is `changeChar`. It's actually very close to a very common Haskell `Prelude` function called `const`. To get `changeChar` we just need to `flip const`.

```
const :: a -> b -> a
const a b = a

changeChar :: Char -> Char -> Char
changeChar     = flip const
--             = flip (\a _ -> a)
--             = \_ a -> a
--         _ a = a
```

Beyond that, your code is fairly reasonable, but can be cleaned up by using a function `splitAt`

```
splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAt n xs           =  (take n xs, drop n xs)

changeChar x char xs = 
  let (before, _it:after) = splitAt (x - 1)
  in before ++ (char:after)
```

which also highlights a slight problem with this definition in that if your index is too large it will throw a pattern matching failure. We could fix that by making the function return an unmodified string if we "fall off the end"

```
changeChar x char xs = 
  let (before, after) = splitAt (x - 1)
  in case after of
    []       -> []
    (_:rest) -> char:rest
```

There's a general pattern here as well of applying a modifying function at a particular place in a list. Here's how we can extract that.

```
changeAt :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
changeAt n f xs = 
  let (before, after) = splitAt (n-1)
  in case after of
    []       -> []
    (x:rest) -> (f x):rest
```

We can use this to iterate the notion

```
-- | Replaces an element in a list of lists treated as a matrix.
changeMatrix :: (Int, Int) -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
changeMatrix (i, j) x = changeAt i (changeAt j (const x))
```

Comment: Actually, `const a b = a`, but it's basically the same thing.

Comment: Yup, fixed it but also added a bit about `splitAt`.

Comment: Is that function totally the same as what I have done here : 

changeChar :: Char -> Char -> Char
changeChar x y = y

Comment: `flip const` is, as @bheklilr pointed out. Or rather, `changeChar` is a specialization of `flip const` where `a` and `b` are `Char`. My original answer had a mistake which has been corrected now.

Comment: Ok thanks. But what if I had the question of :

Changing a Char to another specified Char in a specified position in a [String] meaning a list of Strings ? Is it similar to the answer for changing a Char within a String ? Here is what I have done for it :


-- Changes a Char to another specified Char in a specified position in a Canvas
changeRaw :: Char -> Int -> Int -> Canvas -> Canvas
changeRaw char x y zs = (take (y-1) zs) ++ [(changeStr x char (zs !! (y-1)))] ++ (drop y zs)

Is there anyway to shorten this ?

Comment: You can use the exact same `splitAt` trick. I'll add a generalized answer.

Comment: I basically want to know the shortest way of changing a Char to another specified Chat in a specified position in a[String] meaning in a  list of Strings

Comment: If you look at `changeMatrix` carefully that is exactly what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is pretty much what you need, except the function `changeChar` is just `flip const`, and you could rewrite yours as

```
changeStr x char zs = take (x-1) zs ++ [char] ++ drop x zs
```

If you wanted to be complicated, you could use `splitAt` from `Data.List` and the fact that `fmap f (a, b) = (a, f b)`

```
changeStr idx c str = uncurry (++) $ fmap ((c:) . tail) $ splitAt (idx - 1) str
```

And if you wanted to be really complicated, you could ask the `pointfree` bot how to write it without explicit function arguments

```
changeStr = ((uncurry (++) .) .) . flip ((.) . fmap . (. tail) . (:)) . splitAt . subtract 1
```